# Scrapy request callback doesn't firing

Tags: python, callback, request, scrapy

I am new to scrapy.

I want to scrap A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C -> ... circlely.

but, request after item_scraped callback is not firing.

I don't know why callback function is not firing?

below is my spider code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
import time
import settings

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from items import StudentID, StudentInfo

class GetidSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "getid"

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES' : {
            'pipelines.GetidPipeline' : 300
        }
    }

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(GetidSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_scraped, signal = signals.item_scraped)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal = signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def __init__(self, login_id = None, login_pwd = None, Center = None):
        self.login_id = login_id
        self.login_pwd = login_pwd
        self.CENTER = Center

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/index.jhtml", self.login) 

    def login(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname = 'Logon',
            formdata = {
                'login' : self.login_id,
                'password' : self.login_pwd
            },
            callback=self.get_student_id
        )

    def get_student_id(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//title/text()').extract():
            if title == "SDS : Main":
                self.student_info_count = 3
                return scrapy.Request('http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/followup/studyrecord/studentstudyrecord.jhtml',
                                     callback=self.print_student_info)

    def print_student_info(self, response):
        print self.student_info_count
        if self.student_info_count > 0:
            print "in if"
            yield scrapy.Request('http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/followup/studyrecord/contracts.jhtml?studentCode=18138',
                callback=self.save_student_info)
        else :
            print "in else"
            yield scrapy.Request('http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml')

    def save_student_info(self, response):
        print "in save_student_info"
        print response.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"][@name="profileId"]/@value').extract()
        if response.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"][@name="profileId"]/@value').extract() == "" :
            yield scrapy.Request('http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml')
        else :
            student_info = ItemLoader(item=StudentInfo(), response=response)
            student_info.add_value('item_name', 'student_info')
            student_info.add_xpath('SDS_No', '//table/tr/td[@width="100%"][@class="text"]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))
            student_info.add_xpath('StartLevel', '//table/tbody/tr/td[@class="text"][3]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))
            student_info.add_xpath('EndLevel', '//table/tbody/tr/td[@class="text"][5]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))
            student_info.add_xpath('ProEnglish', '//table/tbody/tr/td[@class="text"][8]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))

            yield student_info.load_item()
            del student_info

    def item_scraped(self, item, spider):
        if self.student_count > 0 :
            self.student_count -= 1
            print "in student_count"
        elif self.student_info_count > 0 :
            self.student_info_count -= 1
            print "in student_info_count"
            return scrapy.Request('http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml', callback=self.print_student_info)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print "SPIDER IS CLOSED"
```

and, below is log.

```
2016-11-19 18:42:36 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-19 18:42:36 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-19 18:42:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-19 18:42:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-11-19 18:42:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/index.jhtml> (referer: None)
2016-11-19 18:42:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml> from <POST https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/index.jhtml?_DARGS=/index.jhtml.3&_dynSessConf=4369572730097781326>
2016-11-19 18:42:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml> from <GET https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml>
2016-11-19 18:42:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml> (referer: https://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/index.jhtml)
2016-11-19 18:42:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/followup/studyrecord/studentstudyrecord.jhtml> (referer: http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml)
3
in if
2016-11-19 18:42:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/followup/studyrecord/contracts.jhtml?studentCode=18138> (referer: http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/followup/studyrecord/studentstudyrecord.jhtml)
in save_student_info
[u'E530633464']
2016-11-19 18:42:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/followup/studyrecord/contracts.jhtml?studentCode=18138>

None
in student_info_count
2016-11-19 18:42:40 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
SPIDER IS CLOSED
2016-11-19 18:42:40 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 3500,
 'downloader/request_count': 7,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18150,
 'downloader/response_count': 7,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 19, 9, 42, 40, 192000),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 19, 9, 42, 36, 494000)}
2016-11-19 18:42:40 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
Done
[Finished in 5.6s]
```

below is pipeline code

```
class GetidPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print item
    def __del__(self):
        pass
```

Log looks just one page scrap and done..

I don't know what's happening

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Requests (and Items) in Scrapy can only be handled by the `crawler.engine` object, that's why spider callback methods are (without you noticing it) being handled internally by this object.

This doesn't happen with signal methods, pipelines, extensions, middlewares, etc. Only on spider callback methods.

So normally, when you want to crawl a site and then return an item, you just call every request in chains, since the `start_requests` method, and then until the last callback returns an item. Despite that, you could also force Scrapy to add a Request into its engine, with this:

```
self.crawler.engine.crawl(
    Request(
        'http://sdszone1.e-wsi.com/standard/index.jhtml',
        callback=self.print_student_info,
    ),
    spider,
)
```

Comment: you should haven edit option on your question, but what's the problem?